# Pattern for fast copy in C

Tags: c++, c, design-patterns

I once saw a programming pattern (not design), how to implement a fast copy of buffers. It included an interleaved loop and switch. The thing was, it copied 4 bytes most of the time, only the last few bytes of the buffer were copied using smaller datatypes.

Can someone tell me the name of it? It's named after a person. It's done in C and the compiler output is nearly optimal.

Comment: Modern compilers does better memcpy when you call memcpy directly and the Duff device is interesting but hard for compiler to optimize. It is an ancient method, not recommended to use in new code. Even X.org deleted all Duffs and get speed increase.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It sounds like you're thinking of [Duff's device](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duff%27s_device).

Answer (score 12):

Use `memcpy()`, it's standard, portable and in many cases optimized well too.

Comment: you are right - that's the thing to use. I just wanted to know the pattern (though not using it).

Comment: Duff's device is optimised to reduce the cost of testing the loop conditional, but in its most common form copies a byte at a time. memcpy is typically optimised to the word size of the architecture, possibly also including some unrolling to reduce the number of tests, and only copying bytes at either end of unaligned buffers

Comment: memcpy may also make use of other tricks, using SIMD instructions, or even DMA transfers.

Comment: jalf, where (machines, cpus, oses, libcs) does memcpy uses DMA transfers?

Comment: I have an implementation I wrote myself where it uses DMA on Zilog ZNEO.

Comment: but `memcpy()` is not that much useful to copy locations marked as `volatile`. Casting away the `volatile` doesn't serve the purpose.

Answer (score 2):

[Duff's device](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duff%27s_device)

Answer (score 2):

It is called Duff's device, see on  [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duff%27s_device)

If you want to implement / utilize a fast copy, then first look at your compiler's implementation; it might use a lot more sophisticated algorithm using advanced features of your CPU. The Intel compilers have pretty sophisticated versions for example.